# Where is the message in the transaction bundle?

Tags: transaction, bundles, legacy-protocol, ternary

I am working with the nodeJS lib. I made a transaction with an address, amount, message and tag as inferred from api.prototype.prepareTransfers in the JSlib. Then I looked up that transaction with api.getBundle. It gave me a whole lot of trytes.
I found the tag, and after removing the trailing 9's was able to convert it back with Utils.fromTrytes. But I never found the message in there.

Where can I find that? What am I missing ? Here are the trytes:

[{"hash":"TDFXQNGTLMCZLJZDCZAQTTCUONZ9MBVWCECZPQHOYMLMLNPQZGZGTOJGQVWHCI9YRVJCEMQAXNFVA9999","signatureMessageFragment":"GACDZCTCEAADTCGDGDPCVCTCGA9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999","address":"FKIXXQEHPUMCAXEKPUERAYTZBFLNT9FBSZGKZSIYLMSFVLAJRFLPFPWOTCZYCMM9NFLZKISDEUFMSTNDZ","value":1,"obsoleteTag":"CCTCBDBDBDEASCTCEAHDPCVCGA9","timestamp":1513808981,"currentIndex":0,"lastIndex":2,"bundle":"B9EVNFDKAUNZCXYFSBVKWPDYVKIKFFXKBGZLOHIBUZNPVQQLQVKAUFKWMEEAZKHTHJ9WKWAC9YECHDTEC","trunkTransaction":"CQDPNDQOOZEZUZXTQBUISEYWDIHYRQQEFEFTBDDSUJUIKDDYRUZQLXGYRCLCVJCWDK9EQOUBUL9X99999","branchTransaction":"XIWXXIUQ9DYTWDAELVPGNYNKTHOSFFUHBIZ9RRQWPZCAZETAHXIWYPSEGZGABCMPOHLUVIXZJMXTZ9999","tag":"GATCBDBDBDEASCTCEAHDPCVCGA9","attachmentTimestamp":0,"attachmentTimestampLowerBound":0,"attachmentTimestampUpperBound":0,"nonce":"BA99999999XFB99999999999999"},{"hash":"CQDPNDQOOZEZUZXTQBUISEYWDIHYRQQEFEFTBDDSUJUIKDDYRUZQLXGYRCLCVJCWDK9EQOUBUL9X99999","signatureMessageFragment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address":"GDHPTALLKXGXOQXOFNWFYTDTGW9QFWZLSEH9SPZISBSQ99QJOXDVHDRJKVQD9PBDOFFDTYYZLOGUTFAN9","value":-1,"obsoleteTag":"GATCBDBDBDEASCTCEAHDPCVCGA9","timestamp":1513808981,"currentIndex":1,"lastIndex":2,"bundle":"B9EVNFDKAUNZCXYFSBVKWPDYVKIKFFXKBGZLOHIBUZNPVQQLQVKAUFKWMEEAZKHTHJ9WKWAC9YECHDTEC","trunkTransaction":"BHEWKNEXOUCUKQUQATMUHLLMNCCCKOGPUN9GZTD9SWBYNZVBXBFKLKYAUFYLCRVUBIWPVNLNZYQCZ9999","branchTransaction":"XIWXXIUQ9DYTWDAELVPGNYNKTHOSFFUHBIZ9RRQWPZCAZETAHXIWYPSEGZGABCMPOHLUVIXZJMXTZ9999","tag":"GATCBDBDBDEASCTCEAHDPCVCGA9","attachmentTimestamp":0,"attachmentTimestampLowerBound":0,"attachmentTimestampUpperBound":0,"nonce":"HJB99999999SA99999999999999"},{"hash":"BHEWKNEXOUCUKQUQATMUHLLMNCCCKOGPUN9GZTD9SWBYNZVBXBFKLKYAUFYLCRVUBIWPVNLNZYQCZ9999","signatureMessageFragment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address":"GDHPTALLKXGXOQXOFNWFYTDTGW9QFWZLSEH9SPZISBSQ99QJOXDVHDRJKVQD9PBDOFFDTYYZLOGUTFAN9","value":0,"obsoleteTag":"GATCBDBDBDEASCTCEAHDPCVCGA9","timestamp":1513808981,"currentIndex":2,"lastIndex":2,"bundle":"B9EVNFDKAUNZCXYFSBVKWPDYVKIKFFXKBGZLOHIBUZNPVQQLQVKAUFKWMEEAZKHTHJ9WKWAC9YECHDTEC","trunkTransaction":"XIWXXIUQ9DYTWDAELVPGNYNKTHOSFFUHBIZ9RRQWPZCAZETAHXIWYPSEGZGABCMPOHLUVIXZJMXTZ9999","branchTransaction":"XAUKTLYOVWWARZZTVSXIQSUGNDNJQKIMAGSFNJQURDZUHSWJJMOSUJT9UYXCMQTJ9MDVZBRXRVBD99999","tag":"GATCBDBDBDEASCTCEAHDPCVCGA9","attachmentTimestamp":0,"attachmentTimestampLowerBound":0,"attachmentTimestampUpperBound":0,"nonce":"CAD9999999XXH99999999999999"}]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is stored in the space where the signature normally would be. In the signatureMessageFragment of the first transaction in the bundle, there is GACDZCTCEAADTCGDGDPCVCTCGA and a whole lot of 9's. These trytes translate to "oke message" as you can see on the ASCII Message to Trytes converter [here](https://laurencetennant.com/iota-tools/index.html).

Comment: ahhh perfect! Is it always stored there? Seems a bit confusing .. ?

Comment: It's called the signatureMessageFragment because it can hold either a signature or a message, which may be fragmented over multiple transactions in a bundle.

Comment: Allright. Thanks. I am going to look into that part anyway. Got a good place to start!